# CFBundleDisplayName has no function

Tags: iphone

I add the codes

```
CFBundleDisplayName="MyAppInFrench";
```

to the file Localizable.strings of fr.lproj

and I also set 'Application has localized display name' to checked.

But app name in French environment still display 'MyAppInEnglish",

it look likes CFBundleDisplayName does not work

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow  the simple step for localize the value of `CFBundleDisplayName` in the **Info.plist** file...

1->Create an **en.lproj** directory if your project doesn’t already have one.

2->Inside the **en.lproj** directory create a file called **InfoPlist.strings.**

3->Add this line to the file: **”CFBundleDisplayName” = “YourNewAppName”;**

change your file name `Localizable.strings` to `InfoPlist.strings`

Comment: what if you wanted to set this for a locale like en_CA or en_GB instead of a language based setting. THis doesn't seem to work